# Rails 4 welcome wizard, how to correct this code to make it work for rails 4?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, delegates

Try to build a welcome wizard and try to get existing rails code to be ported to be rails 4 compatible. Based mostly on previous great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17255451/355281

```
I try to call http://books:3000/welcome/basics
```

This results in:

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant WelcomeController
```

**app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb**

```
class Welcome::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
  layout "welcome" 
  before_filter :authentice_user!   
end
```

**app/controllers/welcome_basics_controller.rb**

```
class Welcome::BasicsControlller < Welcome::ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :allowed?

  def new
    @step = Welcome::Basics.new(current_user)
  end

  def create
    @step = Welcome::Basics.new(current_user)
    if @step.save(params[:welcome_basics])
      redirect_to welcome_some_other_step_path, :notice => "Yay"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def step
    @step ||= Welcome::Basics.new(current_user)
  end

  helper_method :step

  def allowed?
    redirect_to previous_step_path unless step.allowed?
  end

end
```

**app/models/welcome_basics.rb

```
class Welcome::Basics

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  attr_reader :user

  delegate :some_field, :some_other_field, :to => :user

  validates_presence_of :some_field

  def save(params)
    user.some_field = params[:some_field]
    user.some_other_field = params[:some_other_field]
    if valid?
      user.step = 2
      user.save
    end
  end

  def photo
    @photo ||= Photo.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile ||= user.profiles.first
  end

end
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
  namespace :welcome do
    resource :basics, :only => [:new, :create]
  end
```

Comment: Is there a reason to split these two controllers instead of using just one?

Comment: Have you attempted to implement my solution?  What issues are you still having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few things that appear to be off. The one that appears to be the biggest issue with Rails 4 vs Rails 3.2 is in your pseudo-model definition.

```
class Welcome::Basics

  include ActiveModel::Model # Necessary for Rails 4

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  ...

end
```

In your `welcome_controller.rb`, you have `authentice user` which should read `authenticate user`.

In your `welcome_basics_controller.rb` you misspelled controller in your definition, currently: `Welcome::BasicsControlller` should be `Welcome::BasicsController`.

I'd also recommend that you change your naming and inheritance to be a bit simpler and more inline with Rails convention over configuration.  This would be my approach:

Since welcome_basics.rb is a pseudo-model, I'd put it in its own directory to prevent any potential automatic sourcing of ActiveModel. I'd also change the name to the singular to be in line with Rails conventions for models.

**app/pseudo_models/welcome_basic.rb**

```
class WelcomeBasic

  include ActiveModel::Model # Necessary for Rails 4

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  ... 

end
```

Now I'd put your welcome_controller in a sub-directory called "welcome" within the controller directory:

**app/controllers/welcome/welcome_controller.rb**

```
class Welcome::WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  layout "welcome" 
  before_filter :authenticate_user!   
end
```

Then your basics controller should be called basics within the "welcome" directory, and since your inheriting from your welcome controller, you don't need to repeat the `authenticate_user!` line.  Also remember that you'll need to rename your calls to your pseudo-model from `Welcome::Basics` to `WelcomeBasic`.  For Rails 4 you'll also need to implement strong params in your controller.

**app/controllers/welcome/basics_controller.rb**

```
class Welcome::BasicsController < Welcome::WelcomeController

  before_filter :allowed?

  def new
    @step = WelcomeBasic.new(current_user)
  end

  def create
    @step = WelcomeBasic.new(current_user)
    if @step.save(basic_params) #updated to use strong_params
      redirect_to welcome_some_other_step_path, :notice => "Yay"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  #For strong_params
  def basic_params
    params.require(:welcome_basic).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2)
  end


  def step
    @step ||= WelcomeBasic.new(current_user)
  end

  helper_method :step

  def allowed?
    redirect_to previous_step_path unless step.allowed?
  end

end
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
...
  namespace :welcome do
    resources :basics, :only => [:new, :create]
  end
...
```

The other thing that you'll need to ensure is that your corresponding views are placed within the same directory structure as your controller, so you should have the following:

**/app/views/welcome/basics/welcome.html.erb**

One other note, when you say "I try to call `http://books:3000/welcome/basics`", I assume you mean that your attempting to post your form?  Otherwise, you should be calling  `http://books:3000/welcome/basics/new` in order to get your basics form.  If you want that route to map to `http://books:3000/welcome/basics` you'll need to make the corresponding adjustments in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Use `rails generate controller welcome/basics` and it will create the proper directories for you.

Comment: Ok great writeup thanks got me a bit more in the right direction. How would one let the welcome controller update the profile ? Its still routing to my profiles controller -ofcourse- when I have simple_form_for @profile

Comment: The problem is im using the @profile model to store all my values, currently this implementation depends on welcome_basics model hold these values which adds an extra complexity. If adding those profile attributes to attr_accessible perhaps

Comment: 1) You can tell simple_form_for which route you would like it to use. 2) The premise that your whole setup is based on the use of a pseudo-model (I've suggested using WelcomeBasic naming for this pseudo-model) to store your attributes from step to step, once you have all the attributes, then you'd save them to an actual model. Try the following: `simple_form_for(:welcome_basic, url: welcome_basics_path) do |f|`   Note: If you add your view code, that would be helpful in diagnosing the issues your encountering there more thoroughly, and I can update my answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Paul Im going to dive into this and hopefully be able to refactor my old code and get it working. thanks again for your  very informative writeup!